# verifying dmi pool data grub When trying to install ubuntu using usb , getting this error verifying dmi pool data grub Please help me

Tags: software-installation

In my desktop pc, I was unable to install UBUNTU 23 using bootable usb .
Giving error like "Verifying DMI pool data.... GRUB"
It is not going further.
My desktop pc specifications are
4gb ddr2 RAM
500gb hard disk
Core 2 duo processor
Gsonic mother board

Please help me

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 23 product, this replies have needed to be generic.  Ubuntu 23.04 & 23.10 are available in various forms (two ISOs available for Desktop download/installs, two installers available with you selecting which you use at download by ISO selected, another for Ubuntu Server, plus *flavor* ISOs which use three different installers (one *flavor* offers a choice of two installers selected by ISO download).  You didn't specify which you attempted; or if it was a *forgery* (there is no Ubuntu 23) so I'd suggest checking your facts.